# How does the ECMA Script 5 spec allow successful parses for hex ints greater than 0xFF?

Tags: javascript, parsing, ecmascript-5, hex, ecma262

In [EMCA262 version 5.1](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/) the definition of a hexadecimal integer literal is: (document page 20, PDF page 32)

> *HexIntegerLiteral* ::
>         `0x`*HexDigit*
>         `0X`*HexDigit*
>         HexIntegerLiteral *HexDigit*
>
> *HexDigit* :: **one of**
>         `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f A B C D E F`

The way I understand it an HIL can look like this:

(HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL HD))))))

An HIL can look like `0x0` (that is `0x` and a Hex Digit) and an HD can be `0`, so an HIL can be `0x00x00x00x00x00`

Obviously no implementation works like this, so I'm clearly misunderstanding something. How should I interpret (in my mind) this recursive definition?

Comment: In general you know that you must write it as `0x0000`?

Comment: Yes, I know how hex should look n_n;

Comment: Okay I was not sure ;-) so I'm not sure what your problem is... The definition is for *HexIntegerLiteral* `0x HexDigit` or `HexIntegerLiteral HexDigit`. So I see in that definition no hint for that.

Comment: Yeah, I accepted my interpretation was wrong before I asked. I just couldn't see why it was wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition may be recursive but it doesn't work like that. Basically, it says that a HexIntegerLiteral is one of:

- the case-insensitive prefix `0x` followed by *one hex digit*, or
- a HexIntegerLiteral followed by *one hex digit*

`0x00x00` does not follow this definition. Here is why:

#### `0x0`

This is obviously a HIL by the first production.

#### `0x00`

This is also a HIL by the second production: the HIL `0x0` (established above) is followed by the hex digit `0`.

#### `0x00x`

This is not a HIL, because:

1. It is obviously not a result of the first production
2. It is also not a result of the second production: the established HIL `0x00` from above is followed by something other than a hex digit.

In other words, the grammar above does not allow this:

```
(HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL (HIL HD))))))
```

What it allows is this:

```
(HIL (HD (HD (HD (HD (HD))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

HexIntegerLiteral is defined as `0X` or `0X` followed by one of `0-F`, like...

```
//  vv----`0x`
    0x5
//    ^---Hex Digit
```

...OR as `HexIntegerLiteral` followed by one of `0-F`, like...

```
//  vvv----HexIntegerLiteral
    0x54
//     ^---Hex Digit
```

...or...

```
//  vvvv----HexIntegerLiteral
    0x546
//      ^---Hex Digit
```

It may seem clearer if you work backwards.